# How to include Google Analytics in my app

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am trying to include Google Analytics in my app, but after following Google's [guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) I ended up nowhere.

For some reason I did not see any activity in my Google's Analytics account. So I am asking for a simple guide to follow. Does anybody know of a good tutorial of how to include analytics in my app?

Comment: http://java.dzone.com/articles/working-google-analytics-api Please check it out may be helpful ti you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Having a quick look, it seems very detailed and to the point. I will try it on and hopefully it will for fine on my app. Thank you again good Sir! :)

Comment: @RajanBhavsar This was very helpful. Now everything works. Would you add your commend as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Georgi May i share with that as my answer  with you?

Comment: yes, that would be great! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80877/discussion-between-rajan-bhavsar-and-georgi-koemdzhiev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link that would help to integrate Google Analytics in Android:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/working-google-analytics-api